# LCD screen failure, symptoms and resolutions

Tags: lcd

I own a Samsung 305T Plus, got it 18 months ago. It worked great for photo editing and gaming until recently. For some reason, no matter what is the device I plug to the monitor through the DVI connector, the image seems "dithered", as if the driver would only allow me to display 256 colors instead of 16.7M. I provide a capture of my monitor I took with a digital camera with a copy of the original picture:

[image]

As you can see, the image is still present, but for some reason (and I'm still using a native 32-bits color depth resolution), it seems like the image lacks color graduations, just as if I dithered the colors.

**My questions**:

1. **What are these symptoms from**? Inverter? Backlit? Something else?
2. What would be the **possible solutions** to fix this?

I'm aware Samsung could probably replace my monitor, but I read a couple of posts on other forums (with apparently no solutions) where sending the monitor to Samsung would result in having no monitors for a month or two, which I can't afford to wait. I wouldn't mind paying 150~200$ to repair a +1000$ monitor like this one (30" is quite big). This monitor shines, I wish I would just have to replace a piece of hardware to get it fixed.

Comment: gotta agree with Wil & Troggy -- it's an interesting question, from a technical view, but if the thing's under warranty don't waste time.  use that $200 to buy yourself a temporary replacement if you need.

Comment: Sent it to Samsung, they replaced a part and it fixed the flickering (took around 10 days).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is that monitor under warranty?  I agree not having a monitor would be inconvenient for the time being, but sending in for warranty repair might be your best option if no one else is experiencing similar issues and has a known fix.  From what I have seen, it seems to come down to part of the electronics inside and requires an entire new main board.  Monitors tend to have a few modular parts, but most repairs take significant cost due to all-in-one parts used.

Being a 30 inch LCD, I am sure you spent some good $$$ on that.  Personally, I would trust the warranty repair the most as they built the monitor and can get all parts for them. Plus, the work they do on the monitor will be warranteed.  On top of that, they will normally try and make things right if they cannot figure it out either (replace it).

It sounds like that monitor only has one Dual-Link DVI port, so no other ports to compare against.

Answer (score 0):

This is usually down to either the panel or the controller board - but hard to know for sure, I would say 90% possible for a problem with controller board, 10% for panel.

The only real solution is to replace the part with a working replacement (You can always look for faulty components and solder yourself, but I wouldn't recommend) - personally, I would try to get it replaced under warranty.

Comment: Comments deleted as it had nothing to do with the question. Please take user issues offline.

Comment: @Diago, Thanks for keeping the peace and sorry for my part.